# Periods/dots in phrase search not working

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When I use periods/dots in a phrase search I always get no results.

For example: "118. gr."

I url encode the search string and the phrase search works when I dont have periods/dots in the search string. I´ve tried encoding the dots to %2E but same result.

I´m using the is.microsoft analyzer that came with the 2015-02-28-Preview version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. Phrase search is in fact broken when dates or numbers are in the query. You should expect this issue to be addressed early next week. Sorry for the inconvenience.